# How to Crashlytics to Timber in debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, crashlytics, logcat, timber-android

Hi I would like stuff from Crashlytics (including setInt, setString etc.) being reported to Logcat (via Timber, though can be directly via Log as well). During debug I would also like to prevent Crashlytics from reporting crashes to server.

I started by trying to override methods in `CharlyticsCore`:

```
    // From Crashlytics to Timber
    val cc = object : CrashlyticsCore() {
        override fun log(msg: String?) { Timber.tag("CrashlyticsLog").d(msg) }
        override fun logException(throwable: Throwable?) { Timber.e(throwable) }
        // setInt, setFloat etc. call setString
        override fun setString(key: String?, value: String?) { Timber.tag(key).d(value) }
    }

    Fabric.with(appContext, Crashlytics.Builder().core(cc).build()
```

But I don't see any reports in logcat, just initialization reports:

```
I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics Core 2.7.0.33
I/CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
W/CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
TimberOnlyTest online
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly log to logcat. This is an example of my tree.

```
inner class DebugCrashReportingTree : Timber.DebugTree() {

       override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String, 
       throwable: Throwable?) {
        if (priority == Log.VERBOSE) {
            return
        }
       //print to logcat
        Log.println(priority, tag, message)

        Crashlytics.log(priority, tag, message)
        val t = throwable ?: Exception(message)
        Crashlytics.logException(t)
    }
}
```

Then set it like this in your Application class onCreate

`Timber.plant(DebugCrashReportingTree())`

Comment: I want to do the other way around (from Crashlytics to Timber)